# What does gobject.type_register() do?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gobject

In PyGTK, what does gobject.type_register() do? [The documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--type-register) merely says

> registers the specified Python class as a PyGTK type

Well, duh. What does *registering a class as a PyGtk type* do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A PyGTK type can be used as the type of a PyGTK property. To be known to the GObject type system, a type has to be registered. I don't think you actually have to *call* this function in PyGTK, it is probably done automatically when you call `__gobject_init__`.

Sometimes the PyGTK docs are too succinct. In that case you might want to read the [C docs](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/chapter-gtype.html).

Comment: You do have to in some cases (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022594), though I don't know *when* you need to and whether that's a bug.